# Aurelia Fetch client with HEAD method

Tags: aurelia, fetch-api

I have a simple requirement of the fetch (http) client within Aurelia: Make a http request to a url using the method 'head' in order to determine if the resource exists (but without downloading it).

The call is easy to make:

```
this.http.fetch('http://the.url/something.jpg', { method: 'head', mode: 'no-cors' })
    .then(response => { this.urlIsValid = response.status === 200; })
    .catch(error => { ... Handle error });
```

However, the fetch client never appears to enter the .then() method, it always gets caught by the .catch().

1. If the url exists, or there is some other error reported by the server (404, 405, 500 etc), the error object is a 'blank' response (i.e. has the properties you would expect, but all the values are empty).
2. If the url is invalid then the error object contains the message 'Unable to fetch'.

I'm sure I'm missing something, but it isn't obvious what. ***Can anyone offer a solution?***

This is using the Aurelia 1.0.0 Beta.

---

Update: As requested the headers (as captured by Chrome) for one of the requests that comes through as blank..

Url exists:

```
Request URL:https://xxx/the/url.pdf
Request Method:HEAD
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:xx.xx.xx.xx:443
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:278188
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Mon, 08 Feb 2016 00:12:21 GMT
ETag:"955492e4afe7b2199e15cfafd747df27"
Last-Modified:Sun, 13 Dec 2015 01:20:37 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
Via:1.1 xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:g7dK2pGwdnrKAZnkKOvjm0LUyb78dVdiZLB26x-mGbzI8bc9oUa75Q==
X-Cache:Miss from cloudfront
```

403:

```
Request URL:https://xxx/invalid/file.pdf
Request Method:HEAD
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:xx.xx.xx.xx:443
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/xml
Date:Mon, 08 Feb 2016 00:16:12 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
Via:1.1 xxxxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:q1id8NggywGeBF8PrQuU5L5a--EKGLM7x2glBke-rvV45lXV7Ch2Vg==
X-Cache:Error from cloudfront
```

Comment: Can you access the resource using something like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)?  If you can, does the F12 developer tools give you any additional information?

Answer (score 1):

Your response is not blank, it is [opaque](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type). Opaque responses can not be read and are the result for requesting with `mode: "no-cors"`. You need to set mode `mode: "cors"` to allow your responses to be accessed but then, the server should set the proper [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers) when answering the HEAD request.

Comment: I'll accept that possibly the no-cors bit might cause an issue, However the http status value (200, 405 etc) is provided, and surely should be accessible!?

Comment: Is that the real code of your `then()` handler? It could be the catch is being called if there is an expcetion inside the `then()` handler.

Comment: Opaque responses have status code = 0, https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque.